# WPF. Is this possible to show Dock window above some context(exclude using Auto Hide state)?

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

This is Dashboard View

[image]

Goal: ***Settings*** button must open dock window(Syncfusion`s UI control) where settings of app are loaded if dock window hidden. Otherwise, close dock window. And dock window must appear above Dashboard. Dock window must disappear only by pressing ***Settings*** button.

I have done this partially. ***Settings*** button open and close dock window. Appearance and disappearance occur only by pressing ***Settings*** button but when dock window appears the layout of the view become like this(Dock state in use):

[image]

The only way I found to realize appearance of dock window above Dashboard is using AutoHide state. But in this case dock window disappear automatically if you move mouse from dock window.

In case if you will need in XAML of Dashboard View:

```
<syncfusion:DockingManager>
    <syncfusion:DockingManager.ClientControl>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="OrdersRegion"/>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock Text="Customers region" FontSize="20"/>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="Employees region" FontSize="15"/>
                    </Border>

                    <Border Grid.Row="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="Products region" FontSize="15"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </syncfusion:DockingManager.ClientControl>

    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="OrdersSettingsRegion" 
                    syncfusion:DockingManager.SideInDockedMode="Right"
                    syncfusion:DockingManager.State="{Binding CurrentDockState}"
                    syncfusion:DockingManager.DesiredWidthInDockedMode="400"/>
</syncfusion:DockingManager>
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal fully? If yes, please show how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SyncFusion so this may not be relevant. but using raw WPF this would be a simple case of placing your settings panel in it's own grid above the main display so that it doesn't affect layout.
eg.

```
<Grid>
   <MainDisplay>

   <!-- this will appear above MainDisplay -->
   <SettingsPanel Horizontal Alignment="Right" />
<Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for contacting Syncfusion support.

We have checked your query regarding “**Dock window disappear automatically if you move mouse from dock window**”.

We have attached a simple video to use NativeFloatWindow at middle of Dashboard by clicking the Setting button using SetFloatingWindowRect property and to hide the same window when the button is pressed again.

**Sample link:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/257566/ze/DockingDashBoard-1248510496
**Video link :**  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/257566/ze/Float856501553

When window is in AutoHidden mode, the window is open when focus within that window. When focus is lost(click outside the AutoHidden window), window will be hidden automatically. Please refer the attached video.

**Video link :** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/257566/ze/ScreenCapture_12-10-2019_1.59PM1683466041

You can switch a window from AutoHidden mode to Dock state, click the pin button. When pinning or docking, the layout of other dock windows will be changed to allocate space for docked window. You can click the pin button again to change the state from Dock to AutoHide.

**Video link:**  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/257566/ze/DockAndAutoHide1206235360

Regards, 
Niranjan Kumar